# Android App retrieve multiple query's results efficiently

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-cursorloader

I have to query on 6/7 remote datasets through APIs and then show the results in fragments, I am wondering which solution would be the most performant and better for ux.

Should I create a CursorLoader for each fragment or implement another service which use one response at time to create the fragments and show them?

Comment: you can use any `Loader`, for example `AsyncTaskLoader`, it doesn't have to be a `CursorLoader`, when implementig it you can launch multiple queries to your remote API

Comment: So I launch all the queries from doInBackground and inside their onResponse method I send the data to populate the view?

Comment: AsyncTaskLoader has loadInBackground method